# Sahi Pro - not able to get the value from the web page

Tags: javascript, sahi

I am trying to get dynamic text from the web page using the sahi pro script. I used following script to get the text.

```
_setValue(_textbox("j_username"), "******");
_setValue(_password("j_password"), "*****");
_click(_span("Login"));
_click(_span("Home"));

var $date = _getText(_div("/bwc-selected/"));
var $number = parseInt(_extract($date, "/(.*)bwc-selected/", true));
```

The html code display as below:

```
<div class="date-display 20170301 bwc-selected">Wednesday 01 Mar 2017</div>
```

Here, in the above html code I need to get the dynamic date "20170301" or "Wednesday 01 Mar 2017"

no luck till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code as below and I am able to extract the date:

```
_setValue(_textbox("j_username"), "*****");
_setValue(_password("j_password"), "*****");
_click(_span("Login"));
_click(_span("Home"));

_wait(2000);

var $date = _getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));

_wait(2000);

_log($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the "Wednesday 01 Mar 2017" part  with  `_getText(_div("/bwc-selected/"));` just fine. For the "20170301" part, use `_div("/bwc-selected/").className`

Comment: hi - Actuallly, I missed one more element for locating the date. I updated code as  var $date = _getText(_div("/date-display .* bwc-selected/"));

_wait(2000);

_log($date);     and it worked for me.